# Screen Time out hold down during some process

Tags: iphone, ios, ftp

I'm downloading some file with FTP helper, it takes at least 1 to 1.30 minute during downloading process. Can i stop screen time out process Until my download is complete.

Because when screen time out then app goes in background process and FTP does not works in background i tried background thread process but did not work.

So please tell me to hold down screen and active screen while I'm downloading file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be bellow piece of code help's you, You can. To stop your app from timing out and going to sleep you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

and you can re-enable it

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to force your application to stay in the foreground while a file is being downloaded.  Consider adjusting for error states in the case of an incomplete download, and also creating a progress indicator so users know that a download is taking place and should not close the application.

Answer (score 0):

To stop your iPhone from getting locked you can use this code before you are starting the downloading process

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;`

and when the download is completed

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Googled lot for this answer.

I found that the screen time out process is dimming process when  screen is in idle time then
counter start for screen time out and when counter reaches for specific screen time set by user to lock screen it will lock the screen.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

here is the code that disable counter during your process while you are downloading some files then place the above code in that function.

and you can  start counter  with simple 'NO' . better to place 'didunload' or 'willdisapper' method.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];